# tagit: Input not coming as an array

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, jquery-plugins

I am using Codeigniter framework and want to use jQuery Tag-it! to create a "EducationLevel" input form for my users. I have the UI of tag-it working, but I cannot get the user input into a PHP array.

The javascript code:

```html
$('#educationLevel').tagit({
  showAutocompleteOnFocus :true,
  allowSpaces :true,
  availableTags : PROJECTS['configs']['education_level'],
  afterTagAdded : function(event, ui) {
   tagitCallback('education_level', '#educationLevel');
  },
  afterTagRemoved : function(event, ui) {
   tagitCallback('education_level', '#educationLevel');
  }
 });
```

HTML Code:

```html
<li><?php echo form_error('education_level'); ?> 
 <label>Intended Education Level Tag: <i> # Only a Search Tag #</i></label>
 <input type="hidden" name="education_level" value=""></input>
 <ul id='educationLevel'> </ul>
</li>
```

By this code I am able to get the relevant options for the input in the form.

However on selecting any of the options and submitting my form, I am getting an error. On debugging I noticed that the word "tags" is getting populated in the query. This word should not be there and is causing an error.

```html
INSERT INTO `profile` (`name`, education_level, tags, institution) VALUES (xyz, abc, pqr)
```

My function in controller.

```html
 public function post() {
  if($this->profile_service->addProfile()) {
   $datas['add']['result_msg'] = 'DONE ! :)';
  } else {
   $datas['add']['result_msg'] = 'FAILED ! :(';
  }
  $datas = array_merge($datas,$this->_getDatas());
  $datas['add']['sprofileContent'] = $this->input->post();
  $this->_type = 'add';
  $this->_setDatas($datas);
  $this->_view();
 }
```

Code for Service

```html
public function addProfile() {
  $this->form_validation->set_rules($this->config->item('profile/add'));
  if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
   return false;
  } else {   
   try {
    $params = $this->input->post();
    return $this->profile_model->insertProfile($params);
   } catch (Exception $e) {
    return false;
   }
  }

 }
```

Code for Model:

```html
 public function insertProfile($_params) {
  $_params['enabled_flg']     = 1;
  $_params['insert_datetime'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
  $_params['operator']        = '';

  $_params['education_level']    = $this->checkAndImplode($_params, 'education_level');
  $this->db_slave->trans_begin();
  try {
   $this->db_slave->insert(self::TABLE_NAME,$_params);
   if ($this->db_slave->trans_status() === FALSE) {
    $this->db_slave->trans_rollback();
    return false;
   } 
  } catch (Exception $e) {
   $this->db_slave->trans_rollback();
   return false;
  }
  $this->db_slave->trans_commit();
  return true;
 }
```

Code for CheckAndImplode

```html
public  function checkAndImplode($arr, $field) {
  if(!isset($arr[$field])) {
   $ret = "";
  } else {
   if(is_array($arr[$field])) {
    $ret = implode(" ", $arr[$field]);
   } else {
    $ret = $arr[$field]; // Am getting the control here 
   }
  }
  return $ret;
 }
```

I think since is_array($arr[$field]) is returning false my implode function is not getting executed and hence the error. Would appreciate help to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

For posting input data as array append `[]` with input name

Update the input field as below

```
<input type="hidden" name="education_level[]" value="" />
```